# How can i get the first element from an array of character containing float values?

Tags: c++, arrays, linux, pointers

I am trying to get the first element value from array of character containing float.
The character array size is 7, and it's containing two float elements hence size can be assumed 8. I want to get only the first element ignoring anything about 2nd value.
Here is my code-

```
int main()
{
 char cArr[7] = {2.0085,4.52};
 char* charPtr = nullptr;

 charPtr=cArr;
 cout<<"char[0] :"<<*charPtr<<endl;
 float* fPtr =(float*)charPtr; 
 cout<<"char[0] :"<<*fPtr<<endl;
 cout<<endl;
}
```

Here is my output:

```
g++ b.cpp -o b.exe -std=c++0x
b.cpp: In function 'int main()':
b.cpp:6:29: warning: narrowing conversion of '2.0085000000000002e+0' from 'double' to 'char' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
  char cArr[7] = {2.0085,4.52};
                             ^
b.cpp:6:29: warning: narrowing conversion of '4.5199999999999996e+0' from 'double' to 'char' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]

./b.exe 
char[0] :
char[0] :1.43773e-42
```

I am expecting:

```
char[0] :2.0085
```

Any suggestions with the code change?

Comment: Do you understand that a float and a character have different binary representations?

Comment: Basically, you're warning says it all. Do some research on "narrowing and widening conversions"

Comment: Improve the question by explaining what you intend or mean with this: `char cArr[7] = {2.0085,4.52};` As it is it's not what you think it is.

Comment: Your declaration should be screaming compiler warnings at you. Your `cArr[7] = {2.0085,4.52};` declaration, can, at most store `"2.0085,"` in `cArr` which will not be *nul-terminated* and unusable as a string. The remaining chars  `4.52` do not become characters within `cArr`. So, it frankly looks like a train-wreck of a misunderstood declaration.

Comment: Maybe start with something more simple - like: `char cArr[7] = "2.0085";` When you understand what that code means, you can move to a more complicated example

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: No, that does nothing at all like your comment says.  C++ doesn't just turn source code into character strings without being asked.  The actual result will be `{(char)2.0085, (char)4.52, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}` which is `{2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

Comment: I already mentioned that i want to ignore the second value, i am not concerned with 4.52, but that is how the array is. Here cArr is a character array of 7 bytes storing two float elements of 4 byte each.

Comment: @A.Gupta: No, it does not store two float elements.  It stores 7 char elements.  The first two elements are initialized by (lossy) conversion of the float initializers, each to a char.  The remaining five elements are zeroed.

Comment: @BenVoigt, basic idea is character array is having 7 byte storage and float element has 4 byte storage. Can't i print only one float element exact value with a float pointer pointing to a float array elements?

Comment: @A.Gupta: There's no "float element" in your code.  The array elements are `char`.  Each array element is, quite independently of all other elements, constructed from the initializer in the corresponding place in the braced list.  The second initializer is placed into the second element, it doesn't care about the type of the initializer that precedes it.  Besides, your literals never had type `float`.  Those numeric literals were (very briefly, before conversion) type `double`.  Then they became `char`.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I'm lost at how you get `(char)2.0085` and `(char)4.52` to be only 7 characters? The first has `6` the second has `3` -- How is that `7`? Does C++ just ignore `'.'` characters?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: There aren't any characters there, just tokens in the source code.  Do you know the difference between `char a[4] = {"xyz"};` and `char b[4] = {'x', 'y', 'z'}` and `char c[4] = { x, y, z };` ?

Comment: Of course. That's basic optional declarations. If these things are *character* initializers, how is `(char)2.0085` counted as 5? It's 5-digits and one `ispunct` for a total of `6` by my count. As `(char)4.52` would be 3 digits and one `ispunct` for a total of `4`. Where you say they (both) would fit in `7` at the same time is what has me confused.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `(char)2.0085` is ONE `char`.  `(char)4.52` is also ONE char.  Then there are five fewer initializers than elements in the array, so indexes 2-6 become `(char)0`.  These are not character literals, character literals are surrounded by single-quotes (`'`)

Comment: Oh, the cast is only applied to the single leading char in each, 2 chars `24`, got that. The `char cArr[7] = {that mess}` was magic I had not yet seen in any reference.

Comment: @David: No, the conversion is applied to the whole value.  Floating-point to literal conversions truncate (discarding fractions).  If there were more than one digit ahead of the decimal, you could end up with a `char` whose value is anywhere between `CHAR_MIN` and `CHAR_MAX`. (typically -128 to +127).  For all purposes here, `char` is just the smallest integral type.  Nothing in this line of code makes C++ work with characters.

Comment: I'm going to have to say that I need to go investigate this floating-point to literal conversion cast to be then captured in the array. That part of the process I am not familiar with. Thanks for helping me narrow down what it is I have to learn. That is just some wonky syntax -- that may be the next best thing to sliced-bread... I just don't know.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: The way is actually works is very straightforward.  You're being confused by the question into thinking it breaks the usual rules, because OP thinks so.

Comment: @BenVoigt, It means that even if the array is of 7 bytes character storage, only the index 0 and 1 are considered for storage.Remaining 5 indexes are made to 0. Is it mean that only first character (i.e. 2) will be stored for index 0 and another first character(i.e. 4) will be stored at index 1?

Comment: That may be it. Because if we just have `"2.0085"` that can happily go in `cArr`, as will the other, but they both can't go at once. If it is other than that -- I remain confuzzled.

Comment: @A.Gupta: Not "first character".  Floating point value coerced to integer (because `char` is an integral type).

Comment: @A.Gupta To me it is unclear what you are asking. Is the following correct? You have a text string representing two decimal point values separated by a comma - like `2.0085,4.52`. Now you want to take that text string and convert the first decimal point value in a float type variable and then print it. Is that it?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `"2.0085"` works totally different, because quotes make a string literal.  There are no characters or strings in `char cArr[7] = {2.0085,4.52};`, because there are no (single or double) quotes

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: arrgh, in [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377357/how-can-i-get-the-first-element-from-an-array-of-character-containing-float-valu?noredirect=1#comment85756554_49377357) I meant to say "floating-point to integer conversion" not to "literal".  Sorry, that will definitely throw you off if you try to look it up.

Comment: But `2.0085` are all characters, we are not talking about a floating-point number here, just `'2'`, `'.'`, `'0'`, `'0'`, `'8'`, `'5'`, right?

Comment: OOOH, so we are just converting the `float` to `int` and storing the value as a `char` -- light bulb on...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Yes.  Except it's `double` to `char`, but the first one is a "floating point numeric type" and the second is an "integral numeric type" so the process is exactly the same as converting `float` to `int`, just the possible values are limited to `CHAR_MIN` through `CHAR_MAX` instead of `INT_MIN` through `INT_MAX`.  Do note that the final values are `(char)2` and `(char)4`, which are the same as `'\x02'` and `'\x04'` and not `'2'` and `'4'`.

Comment: @4386427, Yes you are correct. That's what trying to do.

Comment: I think the question is clear enough to be answered.

Comment: @A.Gupta OK. Now that I understand your question, I have posted answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you are trying to make your array hold this:

```
float fArr[2] = { 2.0085, 4.52 };
char cArr[7];
memcpy(cArr, fArr, 7);
```

The code you gave does not give you access to the bytes of a float's representation.  `memcpy` will.

However, it's still not allowed to read a `float` out of the char array through pointer casting.  That is a violation of strict aliasing, and results in undefined behavior.  To read four bytes from the array and treat them as the representation of a float, you need a second call to `memcpy`.

Comment: Yes, I want to read first 4 bytes from the array cArr which itself is a 7 byte. Can you provide the code without modifying these three lines-            char cArr[7] = {2.0085,4.52};
char* charPtr = nullptr;
charPtr=cArr;

Comment: @A.Gupta you CANNOT store floating point values in `char` elements the way you are trying to do. You MUST change the way you are populating `cArr`.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions with the code change?

You actually want this:

```
float cArr[2] = { 2.0085, 4.52 };
float *fPtr = cArr;
```

Comment: Its not a float array but a character array of float elements.

Comment: @A.Gupta: The behavior you describe wanting, is the behavior of a float array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you have a text string with comma separated decimal point values. Like: "2.0085,4.52"

Now you want to extract the first decimal point value (i.e. "2.0085") and convert it to a float (i.e. like `float f = 2.0085`).

There are two major problems with your code:

1) The text string initialization is wrong and the char array is too short.

2) You can't do the conversion by casting pointers. You need to call special function that does the conversion (e.g. `atof`).

One way to do it is like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
  // Initialize text string with comma seperated decimal point values
  char cArr[32] = "2.0085,4.52";

  // Extract the first decimal point text string
  char* p = std::strtok(cArr, ",");
  std::cout << "First text string: " << p << std::endl;

  // Convert the text representation to a float representation
  float f = std::atof(p);
  std::cout << "First float value: " << f << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
First text string: 2.0085
First float value: 2.0085
```